# How can I center the second line of a paragraph?

Tags: html, css

I need help centering the second line of my paragraph. I don't know what to do because I'm new to HTML and CSS but I did try to create two "p" and give the second one a "text-align: center" however it was too far from the first line and I feel like there must be a better way to achieve what I want.

This is the HTML sheet:

```css
.p_music2 {
    color: #000;
    font-family: "PT Sans Narrow", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 2.5rem 6rem;
}
```

```html
<p class="p_music2">
    Upgrade today to get your favorite music, movies, TV shows, and
    podcasts. You can join youTunes and stream — or download and play
    offline — over 70 million songs, ad‑free.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the text that you want to center in a `<span></span>` and then set that span to `display: block; text-align: center;`.

`display: block;` will cause that block of code to break out of the flow of the rest of the sentences, and allow you to center it.

```css
.p_music2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "PT Sans Narrow", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 2.5rem 6rem;
  background: #000;  
}
.p_music2 span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p class="p_music2">Upgrade today to get your favorite music, movies, TV shows, and <span>podcasts. You can join youTunes and stream — or download and play</span> offline — over 70 million songs, ad‑free.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create a parent `<div>` element class with the property `text-align:center` and inside that element add your `<p>` HTML elements with the corresponding text. Then set the styles properties of those two elements separately one for the parent `music2` and another for all your `<p>` elements so you can have control over the margins of the `<p>` elements.

```css
html{background:blue; color: #fff;font-family: "PT Sans Narrow", sans-serif;font-size: 2rem;padding:50px;}
.music2 {
  text-align:center;
}
.music2 p{
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="music2">
  <p>
          Upgrade today to get your favorite music, movies, TV shows, and
          podcasts. You can join youTunes and stream — or download and play
          offline — over 70 million songs, ad‑free.
  </p>
  <p>
  second paragraph..... offline — over 70 million songs, ad‑free.
  </p>
</div>
```